# What's the doc root?

Tags: php, localhost, root, clouddb

I'm basically using [this](https://github.com/cloverstudio/Spika-Server/blob/master/install/INSTALL). And at the bottom it says `# open http://"docroot"/Spika-Server/wwwroot/install in browser`. When they say docroot do they mean localhost? And also is there supposed to be an  `INSTALL` File in there? Cause all I see in an `index` and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

Check the installation instructions http://www.spikaapp.com/install-backend.php

The below is mentioned in the link

```
please open http://localhost:8080/wwwroot/installer to finish setup
```

Comment: So i'll have to use Vagrant?

Comment: Or could  I use couchDB? @Shankar